# Return a value instead of a text in CASE Expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to output a value in a column instead of a fixed text. I'm using CASE expression, but it's wrong, how can I change it to return another expression.

The Code:

```
    select serra.CMP_CORTE,
       serra.idc_tubo,
       serra.tip_corte,

    ( CASE serra.tip_corte
            WHEN '4'   THEN 'OK'
            ELSE 'NO'
        END
    ) corte_pe,
    ( CASE serra.tip_corte
            WHEN '1'   THEN 'OK'
            ELSE 'NO'
        END
    ) corte_pt

from fl_qts.res_tubo_serra_feixe serra
where serra.cmp_corte !=0
```

But instead of the **'OK'** value in the **CASE EXPRESSION**, I need to output the value of the **SERRA.CMP_CORTE**.

Look the result:
[Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwltr.png)

Comment: Just replace `'OK'` with `serra.cmp_corte` everywhere in the `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE expression needs the values to be returned with same datatypes. So you can simple use below query -

```
select serra.CMP_CORTE,
       serra.idc_tubo,
       serra.tip_corte,
    ( CASE serra.tip_corte
            WHEN '4'   THEN TO_CHAR(SERRA.CMP_CORTE)
            ELSE 'NO'
        END
    ) corte_pe,
    ( CASE serra.tip_corte
            WHEN '1'   THEN TO_CHAR(SERRA.CMP_CORTE)
            ELSE 'NO'
        END
    ) corte_pt
from fl_qts.res_tubo_serra_feixe serra
where serra.cmp_corte !=0
```

Comment: Generate the following error:
ORA-00932: tipos de dados inconsistentes: esperava NUMBER obteve CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erro na linha: 12 Coluna: 18

Answer (score 0):

you could use a DECODE function.

Your code should be something like this:

```
select serra.CMP_CORTE,
   serra.idc_tubo,
   serra.tip_corte,
decode(serra.tip_corte,'4',serra.CMP_CORTE,'NO') AS corte_pe,
decode(serra.tip_corte,'1',serra.CMP_CORTE,'NO') AS corte_pt
from fl_qts.res_tubo_serra_feixe serra
where serra.cmp_corte !=0
```

Comment: It generate the following error:

ORA-01722: número inválido
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: Depending on the data type of serra.tip_cut you should cast the information with a TO_CHAR ()

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use column name instead of constant text but I think the column data type is `number` and in else portion of case statement, the value is string.

In case statement all the resultant values must be of same data type. So you need to use `to_char` with column name.

```
select serra.CMP_CORTE,
   serra.idc_tubo,
   serra.tip_corte,

( CASE serra.tip_corte
        WHEN '4'   THEN to_char(SERRA.CMP_CORTE)
        ELSE 'NO'
    END
) corte_pe,
( CASE serra.tip_corte
        WHEN '1'   THEN to_char(SERRA.CMP_CORTE)
        ELSE 'NO'
    END
) corte_pt

from fl_qts.res_tubo_serra_feixe serra
where serra.cmp_corte !=0
```

Cheers!!